# Problema com `echo -e`

Tags: linux, shell, bash, scripting, unix

Estou comecando a aprender shell script e estou fazendo alguns scripts simples para treinar. O script abaixo testa se quem esta executando o script esta logado como root.

```
# !/bin/bash
# 
# This script test if you are the superuser

if [ "$(id -u)" = "0" ]; then 
    echo -e "\nYou are the superuser\n"
    exit 0  
else
    echo -e "\nYou must be the superuser to run this script\n"
    exit 1
fi
```

O resultado e o seguinte:

```
rafa@ubuntu:~/Desktop/shell$ ./superuser.sh 

You must be the superuser to run this script

rafa@ubuntu:~/Desktop/shell$ sudo ./superuser.sh 
-e 
You are the superuser

rafa@ubuntu:~/Desktop/shell$
```

O problema e que quando eu tento executar como root usando o comando `sudo`, o comando `echo` nao entende o `-e` como argumento e imprime na tela isso:

```
-e
You are the superuser
```

Sim eu sei, e um problema besta mas estou curioso para saber o porque que isso acontece. Alguma ideia? Como posso corrigir?

Me desculpem pelos acentos, o meu teclado ainda nao esta configurado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema nao e com seu script, ele esta perfeito :)

O problema e so com o seu `shebang`:

```
# !/bin/bash
```

Se voce apagar o espaco entre o `#` e o `!` tudo vai funcionar. Com esse espaco o comentario e so um comentario, nao qual o programa que deve 'rodar' o seu script. O que e executado dai e o shell padrao, o `sh`, e o `echo` dele nao tem opcao -e. Logo, ele imprime `-e` e depois a frase.

Comment: Perfeito! Funcionou. Muito obrigado, valeu a pena tirar esta duvida.